# Action of the dihedral group $D_{2n}$ on vertex set of regular $n$-gon is primitive $\iff\,n$ is prime?

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, symmetry, dihedral-groups

I'm attempting to prove that the action of the dihedral group, $D_{2n}$, is primitive on the set of vertices of the regular $n$-gon $\iff\,n$ is prime.

I'm not wholly sure where to start. I know that a cyclic group that acts transitively on a set of non-prime order doesn't have a primitive action on that set, and I am trying to formulate a proof based on this fact.

Does anyone have any pointers? Thank you :)

Comment: First, note that any transitive group of prime degree is primitive. (Think of the size of the blocks.) That will give you one direction. Then, when it's not prime, just find an explicit non-trivial block of imprimitivity.

Comment: What definition of $D_{2n}$ are you using?